# How to unit test offline scenarios using XCTest

Tags: swift, unit-testing, nsurlconnection, offline, xctest

I'm trying to perform a set of unit tests, which require different network connection statuses. How can I simulate an offline iOS device when using XCTest (in Swift)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one approaches to this problem.

Mocking/Stubbing is one, you can use a mocking framework like OCMock or OCMockito and force the method return what you need for each test.

The alternative "classic" approach (which I prefer) is implementing a stub/dummy class that shares the same API with the networking class and again have it return what you need for each test.

The difference is mostly of [philosophical nature](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#SoShouldIBeAClassicistOrAMockist)

The bottom line is that you need a way to force the API to return what you want to test against.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get real world situations, like loss packets, latency, you can install Network Link Conditioner (get it from [Apple download center](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/)), but will affect your pc and simulator. Also, you will  needed to use asynchronous test ([check XCTestExpectation at this tutorial](http://nshipster.com/xctestcase/)) in order to wait for the responses or timeouts.

To do quick simple tests, you can run the unit tests on the iphone and simple set iphone to airplane mode.